# OpenLayers 3: Forcing a vector layer to reload GeoJSON source

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3, geojson

I'm trying to force a vector layer in OpenLayers 3 to periodically reload its data from a GeoJSON source. The GeoJSON source changes from time to time.

After many different attempts using different methods, I think this is the closest I've managed to get so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  map.once("postcompose", function(){
       //start refreshing each 3 seconds
       window.setInterval(function(){
         var source = testLayer.getSource();
         var params = source.getParams();
         params.t = new Date().getMilliseconds();
         source.updateParams(params);
       }, 3000);
   });
});
```

However this is giving me the following (every 3 seconds of course):

```
Uncaught TypeError: source.getParams is not a function
```

Here's all of the other code I'm using to load and display the GeoJSON file. The other layers in the map are loaded in the same way:

```
var testSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    url: '/js/geojson/testfile.geojson',
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
});

...

window.testLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: testSource,
    style: function(feature, resolution) {
        var style = new ol.style.Style({
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({color: '#ffffff'}),
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({color: 'black', width: 1}),
            text: new ol.style.Text({
                font: '12px Verdana',
                text: feature.get('testvalue'),
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                    color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)'
                }),
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                    color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)',
                    width: 1
                })
            })
        });

        return style
    }
});

...

var olMapDiv = document.getElementById('olmap');
var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [paddocksLayer,zonesLayer,structuresLayer,roadsLayer,testLayer],
    interactions: ol.interaction.defaults({
        altShiftDragRotate: false,
        dragPan: false,
        rotate: false
    }).extend([new ol.interaction.DragPan({kinetic: null})]),
    target: olMapDiv,
    view: view
});
view.setZoom(1);
view.setCenter([0,0]);
```

I read somewhere else that getParams simply doesn't work on vector layers, so this error wasn't entirely unexpected.

Is there an alternative method which will reload (not just re-render) a vector layer?

Thanks in advance. I must also apologise in advance as I'll need really specific guidance with this - I'm very new to JS and OpenLayers.

Gareth

Comment: You'll have to show how you load (AJAX) your json file.

Comment: See my edits above - I'm not using AJAX to load the GeoJSON when initialising the map. Should I be doing that? The layer is showing correctly with the additional code above - just not updating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/c73wLe7w/))

You can achieve this with a custom AJAX loader (when you pass `url` to `ol.source.Vector` this is AJAX as well). Then you can reload your JSON file as you will.

You can use any AJAX library you want but this is as simple as:

```
var utils = {
  refreshGeoJson: function(url, source) {
    this.getJson(url).when({
      ready: function(response) {
        var format = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
        var features = format.readFeatures(response, {
          featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
        });
        source.addFeatures(features);
        source.refresh();
      }
    });
  },
  getJson: function(url) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
        when = {},
        onload = function() {
          if (xhr.status === 200) {
            when.ready.call(undefined, JSON.parse(xhr.response));
          }
        },
        onerror = function() {
          console.info('Cannot XHR ' + JSON.stringify(url));
        };
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept','application/json');
    xhr.onload = onload;
    xhr.onerror = onerror;
    xhr.send(null);

    return {
      when: function(obj) { when.ready = obj.ready; }
    };
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for this - I've just had a look at your fiddle too and will give this a try...

Comment: This is fantastic - took a bit of mucking around to work it into my existing code but it works! Thanks for your help - would never have worked any of that out by myself.

Comment: @GarethJones - I'm glad to be useful.

Comment: I hope I'm not stretching the friendship too far here Jonatas, but I'm getting a lot of "Cannot XHR" errors with this code. Could you suggest a way to add a retry loop into this code? I've tried a few things from other StackOverflow questions and others on other websites but nothing that quite fits this structure. If you have any ideas I'd really appreciate your help!

Comment: Well @GarethJones the errors are about wrong URL - the address is not accessible. Are you able to show your code online? Like jsfiddle?

Comment: OK, I've made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=0F17Klrzfh) - it won't run, as it references a PHP file (called via the XHR) and also because I haven't included the HTML - but you can see the code. I'm confident the PHP and HTML are OK. The PHP writes a string to a GeoJSON file. The "Cannot XHR" error only happens when it's rewriting the 'structures' JSON file, and it only fails on about every 3rd-4th attempt. When it happens, my JSON is either truncated or contains a small part (3-5 chars) twice. Could the XHR be 'timing out'? Or could my unreliable web connection cause this?

Comment: I think I may have identified the problem. Since the XHR is running asynchronously, my Javascript code is attempting to read the GeoJSON file created by the PHP script without waiting for the PHP script to complete. As a result the GeoJSON file is only partially written then the Javascript tries to read it - I think this is why the JSON is getting truncated. I'm reluctant to run the XHR synchronously, so I'm going to try to test to determine whether the XHR has completed before trying to read the GeoJSON. I think it would still be worth building in a loop to retry the XHR if it fails though...

Comment: Your fiddle link is broken.

Comment: Actually it's OK - I've worked out a solution. I had two XHRs running separately, and one was triggering before the other had completed, thus resulting in the truncated GeoJSON files. For now I've just added a delay and this has solved my issue. Thanks for your help.